# Удалить все лишнее из полученного текста

Tags: php

С помощью $js=file_get_contents вытягиваю title которые могут содержать в себе "красоты" в виде корон, сердечек и прочего [image: ➜➜ это запрос для поиска]

Далее запрос идет в поиск и естественно - поиск не работает   :(

➜➜  это  запрос  для  поиска
Можно как-то избавиться от красот и оставить только текст на лету?
Сейчас использую urlencode и str_replace мало помогает...

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код

```
$str = '➜➜  это  запрос  для  поиска';
$str = preg_replace('/[^\w]+/u', ' ', $str);
```

Результат

```
 это запрос для поиска
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/8SwCIo/1

P.S. `[^\w]` - не буква, не цифра и не знак подчеркивания, `u` модификатор для работы регулярки с UTF-8.

P.P.S. Вместо `[^\w]` можно `\W` использовать.

Answer (score 4):

```
$text = "Тут текст с emoji";
$text = trim(preg_replace('#\xEE[\x80-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]|\xEF[\x81-\x83][\x80-\xBF]#', '', $text));
echo $text;
```

Comment: ZeroTwink, спасибо!

Comment: Та я и сам когда-то искал подобное, когда работал с emoji впервые )
Не отметишь ответ? )

Comment: Отметил, у меня карма маленькая, не считает пока   :(

Comment: @MicroRu, он имел в виду нажатие на галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: $text = "1111111♛ ➜➜  это  запрос  для  поиска ♛ 2222222"; Вывел результат 1111111♛ ➜➜  это  запрос  для  поиска ♛ 2222222  Не сработало   :(